# Docker with Serverless- files not getting packaged to container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, serverless-framework, localstack

I have a Serverless application using Localstack, I am trying to get fully running via Docker.
I have a docker-compose file that starts localstack for me.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3,cloudformation,sts,apigateway,iam,route53,dynamodb
    ports:
      - '4566-4597:4566-4597'
    volumes:
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/temp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

When I run docker-compose up then deploy my application to localstack using SLS deploy everything works as expected. Although I want docker to run everything for me so I will run a Docker command and it will start localstack and deploy my service to it.

I have added a Dockerfile to my project and have added this

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk update

RUN npm install -g serverless; \
    npm install -g serverless-localstack;

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sls","deploy", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

I then run `docker build -t serverless/docker .` followed by `docker run -p 49160:3000 serverless/docker` but am receiving the following error

```
  This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory. Make sure to reference a valid config file in the current working directory if you're using a custom config file
```

I guess this is what would happen if I tried to run SLS deploy in the incorrect folder. So I have logged into the docker container and cannot see my app that i want to run there, what am i missing in dockerfile that is needed to package it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the `pwd` command inside the container while running it. Try

```
docker run -it serverless/docker pwd
```

The error showing, sls not able to find the config file in the current working directory. Either add your config file to your current working directory (Include this copying in Dockerfile) or copy it to specific location in container and pass `--config`  in CMD (`sls deploy --config`)

> This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory. Make
> sure to reference a valid config file in the current working directory

Comment: Done that and it worked thanks, any idea why my application isn't in there is there something i need to include in the dockerfile?

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I have updated my comment. Please check

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that you have serverless installed
2. Once installed create a service

   ```
   % sls create --template aws-nodejs --path myService
   ```
3. cd to folder with the file, serverless.yml

   ```
   % cd myService
   ```
4. This will deploy the function to AWS Lambda

   ```
   % sls deploy
   ```